# How can I generate a statistical date range report in PHP and MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to make a date range report and this is what I have for far.

Form

```
<form class="daterangeform" method="POST" action="datereport.php">
                <fieldset id="daterangefield">
                    <legend><b>Date Range Report</b></legend>
                    <div class= "group1">
                        <div class = "group2">
                            <label for="fromdate"> From </label>
                            <br/>
                            <input type="date" name="fromdate" required/>
                        </div>
                        <div class = "group2">
                            <label for="todate"> To </label>
                            <br/>
                            <input type="date" name="todate" required/>
                        </div>
                        <br/>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
                <br/>
                    <div class="formbuttons">
                        <input name= "formsubmit" id="formsubmit" type="submit" value="Generate Report" />
                    </div>
</form>
```

MySQL query (it shows 'success')

```
if(isset($_POST['formsubmit']))
{
    $fromdate=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['fromdate']);
    $todate=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['todate']);

    $sql = "select crime_type, count(*) from cases where commitment_date between '$fromdate' and '$todate' group by crime_type;";

    if($db->query($sql))
    {
        echo "success";
    }
    else
    {
        echo(mysql_error());
    }
}
```

This is what I want to achieve. For instance, there are crime types 'Robbery', 'Assault' and 'Traffic Accident'. When I select a date range and submit the form, I want it to count the number of robberies, assaults and traffic accidents in that particular range and display it in a table. I am not sure about the above query working for this. Also, kindly assist me in how to display the values since I am a beginner. Thank you in advance.

Comment: *obsolescne warning*: `mysql_...` has been removed from PHP, so this will not run on new PHP installs. The dedicated mysql API is uses the `mysqli_...` prefix, and has new function signatures so that typos between the two namespaces don't magically still work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a small bit that may help.  You should also switch to using mysqli functions but that is another topic.  I didn't test this so it could throw errors but this is the general idea.

```
if(isset($_POST['formsubmit']))
{
  $fromdate=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['fromdate']);
  $todate=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['todate']);

  ##Added the count alias##
  $sql = "SELECT crime_type, count(*) as count 
          FROM cases 
          WHERE commitment_date 
          BETWEEN '$fromdate' and '$todate' 
          GROUP BY crime_type;";

 ##assigned the query to a variable##
 $result = $db->query($sql);

 ##if at least 1 result##
  if($result && (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0))
  {
     ##echo everything into a table##
      echo "<table><thead><tr><th>Crime type</th><th>Count</th></tr></thead>";
      while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
      {
          echo "<tr><td>".$row['crime_type']."</td><td>".$row['count']."</td></tr>";
       }
      echo "</table>";
  }
  else
  {
      ##There won't be an error thrown for an empty result set##
      echo "<h2>No records found...</h2>";
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. May I know what this error means?    Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, integer given in...... which shows    if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)   line

Comment: The query didn't return a result, it returned false.  I edited the answer with a query that hopefully works.  So, make sure the query works first, then proceed with the remainder of the script.

Comment: *obsolescne warning*: `mysql_...` has been removed from PHP, so this will not run on new PHP installs. The dedicated mysql API is uses the `mysqli_...` prefix, and has new function signatures so that typos between the two namespaces don't magically still work.